# How to take values in one column and have those values be additional columns instead, in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, data-modeling

Say I have a column called 'Fruit' and it has these three values:

```
 ID   | Fruit  |
 010  | Apple  |
 020  | Orange |
 010  | Pear   |
```

Say there are other columns like Profile_ID. How do I get the table to read like this instead, where the values in that one column are now columns of their own, and when a Profile is associated with a given fruit, it'll show a 'X' in that row:

```
ID   |  Apple  | Orange  | Pear
010  |   x     |         |   x 
020  |         |    x    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  If you want a particular profile id then:

```
select id,
       max(case when fruit = 'Apple' and profile_id = ? then 'X' end) as apple,
       max(case when fruit = 'Orange' and profile_id = ? then 'X' end) as orange,
       max(case when fruit = 'Pear' and profile_id = ? then 'X' end) as pear
from t
group by id;
```

If you just want to know if a row exists:

```
select id,
       max(case when fruit = 'Apple' then 'X' end) as apple,
       max(case when fruit = 'Orange' then 'X' end) as orange,
       max(case when fruit = 'Pear' then 'X' end) as pear
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and generic enough to handle any number of distinct "Fruits" and does not require manual typing and explicit mentioning all of them

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT """
  SELECT id, """ || 
    STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(Fruit = '""" || Fruit || """', 'X', '')) AS """ || Fruit, ', ') 
  || """
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY id
  """
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Fruit 
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    ORDER BY Fruit
  )
);
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id      Apple   Orange  Pear     
1   010     X               X    
2   020             X
```